# How can I set row height in a table to be fixed in python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to use this example from the documentation to set the row height to be a fixed value.

http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/table/table-row.html?highlight=table#row-height

(Content in case link breaks)

```
>>> from docx.enum.table import WD_ROW_HEIGHT
>>> row = table.add_row()
>>> row
<docx.table._Row object at 0x...>
>>> row.height_rule
None
>>> row.height_rule = WD_ROW_HEIGHT.EXACTLY
>>> row.height
None
>>> row.height = Pt(24)
```

However, I can't import `WD_ROW_HEIGHT` from `docx.enum.table` giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Calderdale NUT/Google Drive/CDFU/Membership Python/labels test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from docx.enum.table import WD_ROW_HEIGHT
ImportError: cannot import name 'WD_ROW_HEIGHT'
```

Checking the source, the table.py file is there, but only has `WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT` and `WD_TABLE_DIRECTION` in.

My python-docx version is 0.8.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you referred to is in fact future features (i.e. not yet implemented).

Comment: This answers my question perfectly. If there's any idea of when it *will* be implemented that would be useful, but I realise there might not be.